# ASP.NET Excluded View Being Hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a scenario where I combined two Views into one shared View.

Excluded From Project but always gets hit

- Views/Foo/Do.aspx
- Views/Bar/Do.aspx

Exists in Project but never gets hit

- Views/Shared/Do.aspx

The files still exist in source control but they are no longer a part of the project.

1. Why would a View that is no longer a part of the project have precedence over a View that is a part of the project? Maybe I'm thinking MVC is doing more that it does...
2. Does MVC just look for any file that it can find that matches regardless of it being a part of the Project?
3. Is this a potential security flaw if you could drop a file in there with the proper name even though it's not a part of the Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 2 is correct. MVC will search the view folders for a matching named view. Precedence is on a case of more-specific overrides more general (ie the "Do" view called from controller "Foo" will first look for Views/Foo/Do.aspx then look for Views/Shared/Do.aspx). The same is true for partials except the heirarchy prioritises first by extension (ascx) then by the specificity of the folder.

Being part of a project only affects Visual Studio (the tooling such as "go to view", publishing properties etc). Although if you choose to have compiled views then it may make a difference.

It is only a security flaw if you allow people to just drop files into your View folders, in which case they could just overwrite any of the views you had included in your project anyway.